# Overwrite claim using XPM footprint

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, smarttarget, footprint

I am trying to use footprints in XPM with a custom made claim, for a Smart Target promotion.

That claim is created when I pass a querystring parameter to any page in the website.

Promotion works well, and I get the expected results. My problem is when trying to overwrite the claim using XPM footprint.

I have followed these steps to configure it:
http://blog.trivident.com/2014/12/creating-custom-footprints/

I see the footprint in XPM but when I apply a value, my promotion doesn't update. I always get the fallback content or the promotion for the claim value I established before; Current claim value is never overwritten using footprint (or at least I never get the appropiate promotion).

Any idea of what I am missing?

Thank you.

This is what I have done (hope it isn't too long):

To create my claim, first I created a processor that sets the value using querystring; if I don't get the parameter, claim is not set:

```
public void onRequestStart(ClaimStore claimStore)
    throws AmbientDataException
  {
    this.LOG.debug("TeamClaimProcessor");


    try
    {

      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Map<String, String[]> paramValues = (Map)claimStore.get(WebClaims.REQUEST_PARAMETERS, Map.class);
      String equipo = "";
      if (paramValues.containsKey("equipo")) {
        equipo = ((String[])paramValues.get("equipo"))[0];
        this.LOG.debug("TeamClaimProcessor : Retrieved equipo: " + equipo);
        claimStore.put(TeamClaims.TEAM_VALUE, equipo);
      }

    }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        this.LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      }
  }
```

Value of URI:

```
public class TeamClaims
{
  public static final URI TEAM_VALUE = URI.create("taf:claim:team:value");
}
```

I created a config file for my claim:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CartridgeDefinition Version="6.1" Uri="taf:cartridge:team" Description="Team cartridge."
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_ambient_cartridge_conf.xsd">
    <ClaimDefinitions>
        <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:team:value" Scope="SESSION" Description="Equipo elegido por el usuario" />

    </ClaimDefinitions>

    <ClaimProcessorDefinitions>
        <ClaimProcessorDefinition Uri="taf:claimprocessor:team" ImplementationClass="com.tridion.fecron.ambientdata.TeamClaimProcessor"
                            Description="Claim processor that gets team.">
            <RequestStart>
                <InputClaims>

                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <ClaimDefinition Uri="taf:claim:team:value" />

                </OutputClaims>
            </RequestStart>
        </ClaimProcessorDefinition>

    </ClaimProcessorDefinitions>
</CartridgeDefinition>
```

Then I added that config file to `cd_ambient_conf.xml` in my website (it is a Tomcat-Java based website), and I add my claim to the `GloballyAcceptedClaims`:

```
<GloballyAcceptedClaims>
     <Claim Uri="taf:claim:team:value"/>
</GloballyAcceptedClaims>
```

I added this to the app `smarttarget_conf.xml` file:

```
<taf_claim_team>tm</taf_claim_team>
```

In fredhopper instance, I added the claim to the `trigger-types.xml` file:

```
<trigger-type basetype="text" url-param="tm_value" name="Team Value">
    <list-of-values multiselect="true">
        <value>madrid</value>
        <value>barcelona</value>
        <value>athletico</value>
    </list-of-values>
</trigger-type>
```

Then I created my promotions based on that trigger.

When I enter my page using ?equipo=madrid I get the Madrid promotion, etc. **So far it works fine.**

To add the footprint to XPM I added to C:\Tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\SiteEdit\Configuration\SiteEditEditor.xml

```
<footprint ID="equipo" controlID="FootprintRadio" Icon="footprint.sessionlength" />
```

And to `C:\Tridion\web\WebUI\Models\SiteEdit\Configuration\SiteEditModel.xml`

```
<footprint ID="equipo" claimUri="taf:claim:team:value">
                        <title>
                            <value>Equipo de futbol</value>
                        </title>
                        <description>
                            <value>Equipo elegido por el usuario</value>
                        </description>
                        <settings>
                            <isMandatory>false</isMandatory>
                        </settings>
                        <values>
                            <value text="" default="true">
                                <label>(ninguno)</label>
                            </value>
                            <value text="madrid">
                                <label>madrid</label>
                            </value>
                            <value text="barcelona">
                                <label>barcelona</label>
                            </value>
                            <value text="athletico">
                                <label>athletico</label>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </footprint>
```

Footprints are there when I access to XPM. But when I apply a value, my promotion keeps showing the same content, no matter what I choose.

Comment: How did you validate the claimstore never gets overwritten ?

Comment: Muy promotion doesn't get the right content. It does if I enter the web app under the right conditions but not using footprints.

Comment: Did you add your claim to the GloballyAcceptedClaims element in the cd_ambient_conf.xml? I see this is also explained in the blog post you mentioned, but this is I think what allows XPM Footprints to overwrite a claim value.

Comment: Yes, I did, under <Security> section

Comment: Can you update your question with the changes you made, feels almost like a typo or miss configuration in one of them.

Comment: I updated my question as suggested, to add all steps I did.

Comment: It finally worked adding all IPs to the whitelist in cd_ambient_conf.xml, but it only works for predefined values. I guess this is a different problem anyway.

Comment: +1 for the question and complete claim/trigger/footprint example. This would make a nice example or blog post.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this (Spanish) http://www.fecron.com/sdl-xpm-y-smart-target-simulacion-de-footprints/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seemed to solve when I added this in Security section of `cd_ambient_conf.xml`:

```
     <WhiteList>
            <IPAddresses>               
                <Ip>0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255</Ip>
                <Ip>127.0.0.1</Ip>                
            </IPAddresses>          
      </WhiteList>
```